# How do I write this as a single for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have to split the data into four groups and each split data into groups and subgroups like the following. How do I write this as a single for loop?

What I tried so far?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]})

n = round(len(df)/4)


groups = [df[i:i+n] for i in range(0,df.shape[0],n)]

first_group = groups[0]
second_group = groups[1]
third_group = groups[2]
fourth_group = groups[3]


split1 = first_group.copy().reset_index(drop=True)
split1['Group'] = 'A'
split1['Sub group'] = pd.Series(range(101, 105))

split2 = second_group.copy().reset_index(drop=True)
split2['Group'] = 'B'
split2['Sub group'] = pd.Series(range(201, 205))

split3 = third_group.copy().reset_index(drop=True)
split3['Group'] = 'C'
split3['Sub group'] = pd.Series(range(301, 305))

split4 = fourth_group.copy().reset_index(drop=True)
split4['Group'] = 'D'
split4['Sub group'] = pd.Series(range(401, 405))

n_split = pd.concat([split1, split2, split3, split4])
```

Output should look something like the following table:

```
  Data Group Sub group
0   1   A   101
1   2   A   102
2   3   A   103
3   4   A   104
0   5   B   201
1   6   B   202
2   7   B   203
3   8   B   204
0   9   C   301
1   10  C   302
2   11  C   303
3   12  C   304
0   13  D   401
1   14  D   402
2   15  D   403
3   16  D   404
```

Comment: Tip: whenever you find yourself having many variables like `var1, var2, var563`, think about using a list to store multiple objects

Comment: Can you write a for loop that sets up the first group, four times? Now, what do you have to change in that code, to make it adjust for each group?

Comment: p.s if you need to use something other than Alphabetical letters you can manually create your dictionary at the intended length of your group .ie `{1 : 'Week1', 2 : 'Week2'}` then replace the `map(dict(zip..` with `.map(your_dict)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go: [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) method allows you to loop through the letters (be aware of the limit of course!)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]})

group_ord = ord('A')
sub_num = 101
groups_list = []
sub_group_list = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    groups_list.append(chr(group_ord))
    sub_group_list.append(sub_num)
    
    if row['Data'] % 4 == 0:
        group_ord += 1
        sub_num += 100 - 3
    else:
        sub_num += 1

df['Groups'] = groups_list
df['Sub-groups'] = sub_group_list

df
```

```
    Data    Groups  Sub-groups
0   1       A       101
1   2       A       102
2   3       A       103
3   4       A       104
4   5       B       201
5   6       B       202
6   7       B       203
7   8       B       204
8   9       C       301
9   10      C       302
10  11      C       303
11  12      C       304
12  13      D       401
13  14      D       402
14  15      D       403
15  16      D       404
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How do I work with it if I have 100 rows and I want to divide them into four groups? And is there any other way for grouping? For example, what if I want to change the group names to QW1, QW2, QW3, and QW4. ord() supports char and not string , right?

Comment: With 'QWn' (where 'n' is the number) it would be even easier: just `append` to the `gropus_list` the string `f"QW{n}"` with `n=row['Data'] % 4+1`

Answer (score 2):

no need for loops here.

we can use `map` and `cumcount`

personally, i would set `4` as a constant variable so you play around with the `divmod` of your index to make it totally dynamic.

```
import pandas as pd
from string import ascii_uppercase 

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]})
idx = set(df.index // 4)


df['group'] = (df.index // 4).map(dict(zip(idx, ascii_uppercase )))
df['subgroups'] = (((df.index // 4) + 1) * 100) + df.groupby('group').cumcount() + 1
```

---

```
print(df)


   Data group  subgroups
0      1     A        101
1      2     A        102
2      3     A        103
3      4     A        104
4      5     B        201
5      6     B        202
6      7     B        203
7      8     B        204
8      9     C        301
9     10     C        302
10    11     C        303
11    12     C        304
12    13     D        401
13    14     D        402
14    15     D        403
15    16     D        404
```